# Python BeautifulSoup cannot read data from div tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to read data from this div tag from [website](https://finance.yahoo.com/).

```
<div class="Bgc($lv2BgColor) Bxz(bb) Ovx(a) Pos(r) Maw($newGridWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mstart(a) Mend(a) Px(20px) Py(10px) D(n)--print">
```

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"

urlpage=urlopen(url).read()
bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage)

t = bswebpage.find_all("div",{'class':"Bgc($lv2BgColor) Bxz(bb) Ovx(a) Pos(r) Maw($newGridWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mstart(a) Mend(a) Px(20px) Py(10px) D(n)--print"})


print(t)
```

I use findall with BeautifulSoup but output not show anything. It show only this

```
[]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I see you've imported `requests` as well; I get [one item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nVOI.png) in `t` if I use **`requests.get(url).content`** instead of *`urlopen(url).read()`*, although I think [using the `id` attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmSq8.png) (like in TopchetoEU's answer) would be better than using the `class` attribute in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostlikely that the urlopen isn't working properly here and element selection may be a little bit incorrect way. However, the below solution is working fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
res = requests.get(url)
#print(res)
bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
t = [x.get_text(' ',strip=True) for x in bswebpage.select('div[class="Carousel-Mask Pos(r) Ov(h) market-summary M(0) Pos(r) Ov(h) D(ib) Va(t)"] > ul > li h3')]
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
['S&P 500 4,085.17 -32.69 (-0.79%)', 'Dow 30 33,706.91 -242.10 (-0.71%)', 'Nasdaq 11,799.67 -110.85 (-0.93%)', 'Russell 2000 1,918.40 -24.20 (-1.25%)', 'Crude Oil 77.79 -0.68 (-0.87%)', 'Gold 1,873.10 -17.60 (-0.93%)']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the parent of that `div` instead, since it has an id, which is unique by design. Then, since that `div` has just one kid, the element you're looking for, its as simple as getting the element's kid:

```py
t = bswebpage.find("div",{'id': 'Lead-3-FinanceHeader-Proxy'}).div
print(t)
```